# ZFS on iSCSI target

Tags: server, partitioning, raid, zfs, iscsi

I have a linux installation with just one disk for the OS and all other storage from my NAS exposed as iSCSI target.

This works very well but I would like to use a filesystem that supports snapshots, compression etc. So I looked to ZFS.

Do you have any recommendations on how to do this? How would I go about configuring the iSCSI target with ZFS on it. Does it even make sense to do so I terms of performance?

Right now my NAS is configured with all the disks in a storage pool on which I've created one iSCSI LUN and target used for the /home folder on the server. And I've created one iSCSI LUN and target for the /var fulder on the server.

So do I create a LUN for each disk and expose these as separate targets, so I can then use them as disks in the ZFS pool?

Or do I crate one LUN and target and create a single disk ZFS pool?

Hope you have some advice.

Thank you